# Fourier series of the odd extension of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, homework

Using *Mathematica* to make a plot, I noticed that the interval it's defined over must be changed in order to do the Fourier series. How do I change the interval to be on an interval of $[-{\cal l}, {\cal l}]$?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes, I went ahead and did the odd expansion which came out to be f(x) = {x^2+2: -1=<x=<0, -3-x: -3<x<1}.  Changing the interval over to [-l,l] has been a problem though.  Resulting in: f(x)={-3-x: -3/2<x<-1, x^2+2: -1=<x=<0, -3-x: 0<x<3/2}.  The last piecewise part doesn't work though.

Comment: Answer to (d): yes, at x=1, where there is a discontinuity.

Comment: @bills. Isn't the discontinuity at `x = 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to change the interval?

f-odd-extention (fox)

```
fox[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{
    {-3 - x, x < -1}, {-x^2 - 1, -1 <= x < 0}, 
    {x^2 + 1, 0 <= x <= 1}, {3 - x, 1 < x}
  }]
```

which looks this

```
Plot[fox[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: fox]

The Fourier series approximation to `fox` can be computed for 20 terns with

```
fs[x_] = FourierSeries[f[x], x, 20];
```

and it looks like this over the interval $[-3,\,3]$

```
Plot[fs[x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image: for]

and clearly shows a Gibb's effect at $x=0$

Comment: That is true, but my teacher has us set them up with integrals from [-l,l]